# Separate definition and declaration of template member function using enable_if whose template parameter also includes a constexpr member function

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

The following doesn't compile under g++ 8.1.0 on CentOS 7:

**hey.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Valid {};
class Invalid {};

struct Hey
{
  template<typename T>
  static constexpr bool is_valid() { return std::is_same_v<T, Valid>; }

  template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_valid<T>()>* = nullptr>
    void howdy() const;
};

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<Hey::is_valid<T>()>*>
  void Hey::howdy() const
{
  std::cout << "Howdy" << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
In file included from hey.cpp:1:
hey.h:18:8: error: no declaration matches ‘void Hey::howdy() const’
   void Hey::howdy() const
        ^~~
hey.h:14:10: note: candidate is: ‘template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_valid<T>()>* <anonymous> > void Hey::howdy() const’
     void howdy() const;
          ^~~~~
hey.h:8:8: note: ‘struct Hey’ defined here
 struct Hey
        ^~~
```

Amazingly, all I have to do to both compile correctly and get the desired behavior is add a typedef in Hey:

**hey.h (fixed, first few boring lines skipped)**

```
struct Hey
{
  template<typename T>
  static constexpr bool is_valid() { return std::is_same_v<T, Valid>; }

  template<typename T>
  using EnableType = std::enable_if_t<is_valid<T>()>;

  template<typename T, EnableType<T>* = nullptr>
    void howdy() const;
};

template<typename T, Hey::EnableType<T>*>
  void Hey::howdy() const
{
  std::cout << "Howdy" << std::endl;
}
```

**hey.cpp**

```
#include "hey.h"

int main(int, char**)
{
  Hey hey;
  hey.howdy<Valid>();

  // Adding this line breaks the build, as it should:
  // hey.howdy<Invalid>();

  return 0;
}
```

After many tweaks, I've narrowed the compiler error situation to the fact that 1) `is_valid()` is a member of `Hey` and 2) `howdy()` is declared inside `Hey`'s body but defined outside. If you delete the `using` and make `is_valid()` a standalone function outside of `Hey`, there are no issues compiling. If you delete the `using` and define `howdy()` inside the class definition, there are also no issue compiling. But when `howdy()` is defined outside of the class definition, `is_valid()` is declared inside of the class definition, and the `using` isn't present, the compiler fails. Is this correct behavior? Am I looking at a compiler bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matching of expressions in template declarations is based on [*equivalence*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.over.link#5.sentence-1), a concept based on the one-definition rule. For two expressions to be considered equivalent, they must be at least token-by-token identical modulo the renaming of template parameters.

The expressions `is_valid<T>()` and `Hey::is_valid<T>()` are not equivalent (the second has two tokens the first doesn't have), and so the compiler is not required to match them.

`Hey::EnableType<T>` is a type, and is not subject to the strict equivalence rules for expressions.